# Adding flip on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have two javascript function on for flip back and other for flip front. The flipBack and flipFront works when element is clicked. I want this to work on hover too.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work

```
$(self.front).hover(
    function () {
        showBack();
    },
    $(self.back).mouseout(function () {
        showFront();
    });
);
```

Here is the plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/qSgvgVat3cXEjLIpD8x6?p=preview

Comment: Look at the documentation for hover... https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: i have already looked on that but not working for me. Actually i want when i will hover it will call one javascript function and when i will leave the hover it will call another javascript function.

Comment: My guess is the code you are calling has the issue if it still does not work.

Comment: code has not any issue it is working fine on click event but not on hover event.look here it is working fine on click
http://plnkr.co/edit/qSgvgVat3cXEjLIpD8x6?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that will not work. The function **[hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)** expects two functions as parameters. The first function will be called when the `mouseenter` event occurs and the second function will be called when the `mouseleave` event occurs on the element.

```
$(self.front).hover(
    function () {
        showBack();
    },
    function () {
        showFront();
    });
```

Or direct function reference can also be used.

```
$(self.front).hover(showBack, showFront);
```

---

Update:

As you're using AngularJS, use `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave`.

View:

```
<li ng-mouseenter="showBack()" ng-mouseleave="showFront()">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showBack = function() {
    // Code here
};

$scope.showFront = function() {
    // Code here
};
```

---

**Update 2**

Add following in controller

```
self.front.on("mouseenter", showBack);
self.front.on("mouseleave", showFront);
self.back.on("mouseenter", showBack);
self.back.on("mouseleave", showFront);
```

[**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pHeiVatAUVxHLeul7kUE?p=preview)

Comment: i have also use direct function.

Comment: i have also used mouseenter and mouse leave function but that is also not working fine. when i move mouse on all element then mouse out function not working.

Comment: @FarrukhZaman Check the update in the answer, use Angular functions

Comment: check here its flip panel in directive it is working with click if we use there mouse enter and mouse leave it work. But not like hover.

Comment: @FarrukhZaman Check updated answer, added [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pHeiVatAUVxHLeul7kUE?p=preview)

Comment: You have update it is possible without adding this code in controller. but you check it it is not working fine. move mouse on all element it will not work like hover. move mouse from left to right and look. all element just flip one side not go back .

Comment: Still have small issue. its blink on some point however acceptable. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92873/discussion-between-farrukh-zaman-and-tushar).